# Qt & OpenGL: how to render as frequent as possible?

Tags: qt, opengl, timer, game-loop

I'm porting over a OpenGL application from a win32 project to a Qt project.

In the win32 project I simply had a mainloop that kept executing the next frame as soon as the previous was finished.

In the tutorials I find about Qt and OpenGL, they're using timers to control the update of the scene. However, I'd like to render as many frames as frequent as possible - how to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to render as many frames as possible? Are you sure that rendering just as many frames as the monitor can show is not enough? Usually that is 60 frames per second.

Answer (score 5):

> However, I'd like to render as many frames as frequent as possible - how to do that?

Not with Qt. Qt takes full control of the event loop thus not giving you any means of directly performing idle operations. The standard way to perform idle operations in Qt is to use a QTime with a timeout of 0.

Another possibility was using a second thread just for OpenGL operations. However to work reliably you should create a dedicated OpenGL context for that one thread.

Qt simply is not the right toolkit for those kinds of program where the primary task of the main loop is rendering pictures and input and event management are only secondary.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `QApplication.exec_()` takes the event loop. There should be a way to set up a typical render loop using `QApplication.processEvents()` instead. I'm having some success with that and I'll post when I tie some loose ends.

Comment: @Kos: See paulm's comment.

Comment: @paulm Actually I dropped that hackery at some point and ended up satisfied with rendering in a 0-timeout timer. I believe it amounts to running a callback every time event loop is emptied, which looks equivalent to whatever I'd code manually.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling [`update()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#update) at the end of your paint handler.

That will queue up another repaint event.

Comment: Queue up = same problem of what Mat is asking: if it takes too much time to render, and there's too many update events waiting, how is this handled?

Comment: @OlivierPons only calling update after previous paint event finished. it won't update too frequency.

Answer (score 1):

The intrinsic principles of Qt and OpenGL are not about rendering as soon as possible, but it's rendering *whenever* we want (huge difference).

You have to ask for the system max framerate (search for samples in OpenGL i'm sorry I don't rememember where I saw that). Once you've done that, just create a timer based on this max framerate, so you'll get what you want.

Comment: but what happens if a frame takes longer to render and the timer fires before the previous frame finished rendering?

Comment: Then you'll render once each other frame. The timer will be reset **once** the render is finished. So, this way, you'll render as soon as possible, but it's up to you to render fast to keep up with the max framerate. This principle is genius, because it adapts itself to the power of the machine: a slow machine will do 5 fps whereas as fast machine will do 60fps, with the same piece of code, and (the most important) they will **both** work (even though the slow one may give the user a bad experience... anyway **it will work**).

Comment: So I suggest to code based on the examples using timers to control the update of the scene.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't have an "intrinsic principle" of rendering as soon as possible. That's up to you and what you're doing. The fact is that smooth animation looks best when be synced with monitor refresh (which is people usually want when asking for "rendering as frequent as possible").

Answer (score 1):

> However, I'd like to render as many frames as frequent as possible - how to do that?

Use QTimer with zero [interval](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#interval-prop).

Comment: At least with Qt 5.15, this doesn't work. If I do that on one of my examples, I'm getting fewer frames per second than if I run with a 10ms interval.